# C Programming: Initialize Array of Unions

Tags: c, arrays, unions

I have a union defined as:

```
typedef union{
    unsigned b_a: 1;
    unsigned b_b:1;
    unsigned b_c:1;
    int d_e;
    int option;

    int data[7];
}myUnion;
```

and I would like to declare and initialize an array of type myUnion:

```
myUnion myUnionArray[1] = { {.b_a=0, .b_b=0, .b_c=0, .d_e=5, .option=6} }
```

I've tried the above line to initialize the array but I keep get errors when compiling ("too many initializers").

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can only initialize one field of an union, since they share the same storage.

Comment: Please read about the difference between a `struct` and a `union`. You seem to confuse them.

Comment: Thanks.  This explains why I can't find anything with a google search.  I will switch to a struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, You are confused with union and struct.

> Union - union is type whose members overlaps the storage and size of
>   the union is the max size of any member. Hence you cannot initialize
>   multiple simultaneously.

Please find the difference between [struct and union](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-enum-union-and-struct-in-C-programming)
if you are interested in nested initialization, please follow [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization#Nested_initialization)
if you are interested in initialization of array, please follow [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html)